# how to convert object to JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

My jquery  looks like this

```
var formContent ="action=view&msgid="+id;
$.getJSON("myserv.php",formContent, function(json){
    $.each( json, function(k, v){`
       alert( "Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v );`
    });
});
```

in my php file i have an array that i json encode

```
while($message->fetch()) {
    $arr[$i]["read"]=$message->test;
    $arr[$i]["messageid"]=$message2->test2;
    $arr[$i]["subject"]=$message2->test3;
    $arr[$i]["text"]=$message2->test4;
}

$str=json_encode($arr);

return $str;
```

the alert returns `Key:0 Value: [Object Object]`

Any idea how I can get it to return the correct result? How can I display the results nicely in a div or span?

Comment: That's the expected output if you convert an object to a string. If you want to access its properties, then do so, e.g. `v.subject`.

Comment: Markdown note: backticks ("`") are for inline code. To [format code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), indent them an extra four spaces (as Felix Kling did for you). The "{}" button in the editor toolbar toggles indentation. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: use console.log(json) and a browser with a console (pretty much anything with firebug style debug tools) and you'll be able to see much more clearly what is going on with that json.

Comment: Off-topic, the sample PHP `while` loop is missing an increment of `$i`, and possibly a `$message2->fetch()`. Are they also missing in your original code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting it all in a single cell array. And then in your callback, in jQuery, you are trying to loop through the array cell. I'm assuming you want to keep $arr an array (guessing you could have multiple 'read', 'subject', etc) so you should change your js to:

```
var formContent ="action=view&msgid="+id;
$.getJSON("myserv.php",formContent, function(json){
    $.each(json, function(i){
        $.each(json[i], function(k, v) {
            alert( "Key: " + k + ", Value: " + v ); });
        });
    });
});
```

Or, if you don't want a single cell array, and will only return one 'read', 'subject etc, then change your PHP to:

```
if($message->fetch()) {
    $arr["read"]=$message->test;
    $arr["messageid"]=$message2->test2;
    $arr["subject"]=$message2->test3;
    $arr["text"]=$message2->test4;
    $str=json_encode($arr);
}
else {
    $str=json_encode(Array('error' => 'No message'));
}


return $str;
```